# spring.data.mongodb upgrade causes InvalidPersistentPropertyPath exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

We are trying to upgrade the following dependencies in our project:

- spring.data.mongodb: from 1.1.0.RELEASE to 1.8.2.RELEASE
- org.mongo.driver: from 2.12.3 to 2.14.1

but are encountering a problem with DBObject mapping with something that worked in the older versions.

simplified code:

**DevicePojo.java**

```
@Id
private String _id;
private Long appID;
private String UDIDHashed;

** getters/setters **
```

**DeviceRepositoryImpl.java**

```
public DevicePojo getDeviceByAppIdAndUDIDHashed(Long applicationId, String udidHashed){
    Criteria criteriaAppId = Criteria.where("appID").is(applicationId);
    Criteria criteriaUDIDHashed = Criteria.where("UDIDHashed").is(udidHashed);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.andOperator(criteriaAppId, criteriaUDIDHashed);
    Query query = Query.query(criteria);
    return findOne(query);
}
```

**Exception thrown:**

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property uDIDHashed found on com.appoxee.server.data.mongo.pojo.DevicePojo!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:256)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:229)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:204)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.getPath(QueryMapper.java:838)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:729)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper$MetadataBackedField.<init>(QueryMapper.java:706)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.createPropertyField(QueryMapper.java:216)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:122)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword(QueryMapper.java:235)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1664)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:564)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:559)
        at com.appoxee.server.data.mongo.dao.DeviceRepositoryImpl.findOne(DeviceRepositoryImpl.java:41)
        at com.appoxee.server.data.mongo.dao.DeviceRepositoryImpl.getDeviceByAppIdAndUDIDHashed(DeviceRepositoryImpl.java:205)
```

We tried annotating the UDIDHashed field with @Field(value = "UDIDHashed"), as well as @Column(name = "UDIDHashed"), but for some reason it keeps changing the first character to lowercase. Only similar thing regarding this I could find is a bug regarding uppercase field annotated as @Id, but that is supposedly fixed since spring.data.mongodb version 1.5.0.